# Can anchors be used in place of div containers?

Tags: html, anchor

Is there any reason to not use an anchor tag instead of a div tag as a container?

Current code:

```
<a href="#page1.html">
    <div id="container">
        <span>Some content</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Proposed code:

```
<a id="container" href="#page1.html">
    <span>Some content</span>
</a>
```

Here is a live demo that seems to run:

```css
.myClass {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 148px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 1);
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.class2 {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#page1.html">
  <div id="container" class="myClass">
    <span>Some content</span>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#page1.html" class="myClass class2">
  <span>Some content</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Based on the code you have posted, I personally don't see why you need the <div> tags at all.

Comment: @RussJ It's just an example. The content could be text, images, groups of text and images, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This perfectly valid in **HTML5**:

```
<a href="#page1.html">
    <div id="container">
        <span>Some content</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

The only difference is that an anchor tag's default `display` is `inline` while the defautl display of `div` is `block`.

From [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The `a` element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists,
>   tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no
>   interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). This example
>   shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a
>   link:
>
> ```
> <aside class="advertising">
>  <h1>Advertising</h1>
>  <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
>   <section>
>    <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
>    <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
>    <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
>   </section>
>  </a>
>  <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
>   <section>
>    <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
>    <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
>    <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
>   </section>
>  </a>
> </aside>
> ```

---

### upadted answer

The only difference between using a `div` and `span` inside an anchor is their  `display`... as you can see in the example below, the spans are displayed inline while divs are displayed as block elements (of course you can change the default display in css):

```html
<a href="#">
    <span>inline element1</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span>inline element2</span>
</a>


<a href="#page1.html" class="myClass class2">
  <div>block elemnt1</div>
</a>

<a href="#page1.html" class="myClass class2">
  <div>block elemnt2</div>
</a>
```